# Problems with users authorization in Sonar 6.2

Tags: sonarqube

We have a running instance of Sonar 6.2 that's been upgraded from sonar 4.5.x and since the beginning we have used the LDAP plugin to recover user data.

Once upgraded to the 6.2 version we have noticed that we can't authorize new users and groups to projects, because we can't see them.

If we select a project and go to the users tab on the project's permisions section we get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBdvU.png), in spite of having this [users list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Y9W.png). And if we select the groups tab we only see the previously groups assignated and not the rest of the existing ones.

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the list you see on project **Administration > Permissions > Users** is the list of people with permissions on the project. Since you haven't assigned any users permissions on the project, the list is blank by default. Why not show everyone by default? Imagine a SonarQube instance with hundreds of users. You certainly wouldn't want to see them all there by default. Instead, you only want to see the ones relevant to your current context; the ones with existing permissions on the project.

To find your missing users, try entering a username in the search input. Matching users should appear in the list area so you can enable permissions for them.

Comment: As a suggestion for next releases I would add a text like "type here to add new users" because I missunderstood the functionality of the search box. Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: Thanks @amoragon, that's in the pipe: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8019